# How can one respond to the --help flag with Getopt::Std?

Tags: perl, getopt

I want my script to print a help message when it is run with the `--help` command line option. Based on the `Getopt::Std` [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html#--help-and---version), this sub should do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;
use Getopt::Std;

sub HELP_MESSAGE {
    say "HELP MESSAGE";
}
```

But it prints nothing. I also tried adding this, out of curiosity:

```
for (@ARGV) {
    HELP_MESSAGE() if /--help/;
}
```

It actually works, but seems rather sloppy. I know using the `-h` flag would be quite simple, but I would like to have both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation of Getopt::Std](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html#--help-and---version) says

> If `-` is not a recognized switch letter, **`getopts()`** supports arguments `--help` and `--version`. If `main::HELP_MESSAGE()` and/or `main::VERSION_MESSAGE()` are defined, they are called; ...

So try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;
use Getopt::Std;

$Getopt::Std::STANDARD_HELP_VERSION = 1;
our $VERSION = 0.1;

getopts('');       # <<< You forgot this line, and `getopt()` DOES NOT work

sub HELP_MESSAGE {
    say "HELP MESSAGE";
}
```

---

Test run:

```
$ ./t00.pl --help
./t00.pl version 0.1 calling Getopt::Std::getopts (version 1.07),
running under Perl version 5.16.3.
HELP MESSAGE
```

Comment: It seems the missing `getopts()` was the problem. In my original script (what I posted in my comment was a skeleton) I was using `getopt()` without the "s". After re-reading the documentation, the difference is cleared up.